# Purchasing genuine Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I want to start using Ubuntu so I went to software shop today, asking for Ubuntu Desktop installation media.

There were some Ubuntu boxes, like Windows ones. I was told that I should enter a product key from some label when installing Ubuntu. I have never seen copy protection in free software.

I was allowed to copy an [example label PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bgLl.png).

I am unable to download Ubuntu from official website because my computer doesn't have operating system installed and I don't have any other devices.

Where can I purchase genuine Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu is distributed for free. You don't have to purchase it. I wonder why people try to buy it.

Comment: That must be some kind of fraud. They customized Ubuntu installed with that "product key"

Comment: @karel This is not about the "free software". The question is about the customized Ubuntu installed and selling product keys. I don't think it's legal.

Comment: @Pilot6 I don't have operating system installed on my computer. I'm unable to burn a CD/DVD and I access Ask Ubuntu from an Internet café (which is the reason why I use another account).

Comment: You can buy an Ubuntu installer, nothing wrong is with selling it. But there is no such thing as "product key". If the installer requires it, I wouldn't install from it. This is NOT a genuine Ubuntu and we don't know what else is there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ubuntu is **free software**.  It is not only free in cost, but free as in freedom.  That means Ubuntu is free to download, run, copy, distribute, study, share, change and improve for any purpose, without paying licensing fees.

There used to be several places to buy a CD/DVD/USB of Ubuntu but due to the ease of downloading it and burning to DVD or writing to bootable USB, these options have all but disappeared. **Perhaps you can use a public library?**

Personally, I would not feel comfortable buying or recommending someone to purchase an unofficial release of an operating system.

See [Our Mission](https://ubuntu.com/community/mission) and [Licensing](https://ubuntu.com/licensing) for more information.

Comment: I'm unable to burn a CD/DVD now. Where could I purchase it?

Comment: It is not easy to buy because it can be downloaded for free. You can use a USB flash drive as an installer.

Comment: @Pilot6 after damage was caused by USB Killer use, USB ports are no longer available in the only Internet café available to me. It looks like I have to purchase Ubuntu installation media somewhere.

Comment: If there is no other option, you can buy that ubuntu with "product key", install it, then download a normal one and install it again to be safe.

Comment: @Pilot6 it costs $49. Is it OK?

Comment: It's definitely too expensive for a free software ;-) And it is unsafe.

Comment: If you have a friend/neighbour with a windows PC, maybe if you buy them a coffee they can download and make a USB/DVD for you.  cheaper than 49$.

Comment: Most Internet cafes I have been in will burn you a copy, in their spare time, for a small fee.